# Rails ActiveRecord custom validator returns false but model.save is accepted without rollback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

i have a model which defines size ranges like 100m² to 200m². I wrote a validator:

```
class SizeRange < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :non_overlapping

    def non_overlapping
        lower_in_range = SizeRange.where(lower_bound: lower_bound..upper_bound)
        upper_in_range = SizeRange.where(upper_bound: lower_bound..upper_bound)
        if lower_in_range.present?
            errors.add(:lower_bound, 'blablabla')
        end
        if upper_in_range.present?
            errors.add(:upper_bound, 'blablabla')
        end
    end
end
```

My guess was, that when I try to save a new model which lower or upper bound appears to be in the range of an other SizeRange instance the validator would mark the model as invalid and the save action would be aborted.
What really happened is that my model got saved and assigned an id, but when I call model.valid? it returns false (So my validator seems to do what it should).

Is there anything I could have done wrong, or did I not understand how the validators work? Can I force the validator to abort the save action?

Another question:
Is there any way to enforce a constraint like that through database constraints? I think I would prefer a solution on database side.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't see any code where you added that method as a validator method

Comment: Didnt add that piece of code (it is there in my SizeRange class) as I thought it would not add value to the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

```
model.save
```

would be accepted silently and return false. It will not throw any Exception.

You should call:

```
model.save!
```

to fail with validations

Comment: I tried that and get the same result. The validator gets called when model.save! is called, but save! returns true while model.valid? still returns false.

Comment: Thanks for your help, seems like I just used a case which isnt caught by my validator. model.save works and after that model.valid? returns false, because the same saved instance of SizeRange causes it to fail...

Answer (score 0):

You should return false after each errors.add to cancel the record saving

Comment: not required. `The valid? method will verify that the errors collection is empty, so your custom validation methods should add errors to it when you wish validation to fail:`

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was my not well-formed validator function.

The case I checked an which led to confusion:

- SizeRange from 200 to 400 already in the database
- Creating a new one between 200 and 400 like `SizeRange.new({:lower_bound=>250, :upper_bound=>350})`

So I expected that to be invalid (model.valid? -> false) but it was, of course, valid. So model.save did no rollback and AFTER that I tested on model.valid? which would NOW return false, as the newly saved instance would violate the constraint, because it was tested against itself.

So there were two problems:

- model.valid? would also test against the same instance if it already had an id
- the validator would not validate what I thought it would

So I ended up rewriting my validator function:

```
def non_overlapping
    sr = id.present? ? SizeRange.where.not(id: id) : SizeRange

    ranges = sr.all
    lower_overlappings = ranges.map { |r| lower_bound.between?(r.lower_bound, r.upper_bound)}
    upper_overlappings = ranges.map { |r| upper_bound.between?(r.lower_bound, r.upper_bound)}

    if lower_overlappings.any?
        errors.add(:lower_bound, 'lower bla bla')
    end
    if upper_overlappings.any?
        errors.add(:lower_bound, 'upper bla bla')
    end
end
```

The first line handles the first problem and the rest handles the intended validation.

Thanks for your help and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using begin and rescue:

```
class SizeRange < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :non_overlapping

  private
    def non_overlapping
      lower_in_range = SizeRange.where(lower_bound: lower_bound..upper_bound)
      upper_in_range = SizeRange.where(upper_bound: lower_bound..upper_bound)

      begin
        raise("Lower Bound Met!") if lower_in_range.present?
      rescue => ex
        errors.add(:lower_bound, "#{ex.message} (#{ex.class})")
      end
      begin
        raise("Lower Bound Met!") if upper_in_range.present?
      rescue => ex
        errors.add(:upper_bound, "#{ex.message} (#{ex.class})")
      end
    end
end
```